# Placing an image over paragraph

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to place an image over a text body. The idea is that I will use jquery animation to increase the image opacity then you can see the text underneath it.

Comment: Could you post the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple piece of code that should start you off.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Display Demo</title>
<style>
.hidden {display:none;}
.block {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 800px;
}
.text, .img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.img {
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block">
<img class="img" src="img.jpg">
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".img").show(5000);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now visit the jQuery docs related to [**.show**](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [**.animate**](http://api.jquery.com/animate) and update it to be what you want.